# DistributedExchangeOperation<ShuffleMoveOperation>

Tags: azure, query-performance, azure-synapse

What is DistributedExchangeOperation in Azure SQL DW Gen2? I don't see this step in Gen1 query plan. This step is taking very long time and because of that for the same data/distribution/Indexing,  same query in Gen1 is faster than Gen2. Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: Please post the query and the EXPLAIN plan.

Comment: This is the Query which is generated by Tableau and if I take the same Query and run in SSMS directly query returns results very fast. The same DistributedExchangeOperation finishes in no time. Does concurrency have impact on the DistributedExchangeOperation ? Basically Tableau sends ~15 queries to backend.

Answer (score 2):

DistributedExchangeOperation is an interim name for the ShuffleMoveOperation.  The DistributedExchangeOperation is performing the same data movement functionality as a ShuffleMoveOperation operation is on Gen1. 
 Running 15 queries in parallel vs. one in isolation can have an effect on performance.  Are you using the smallrc resource class for both the tableau and SSMS version of the query?  Caching can also have an influence run time as well.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I am using staticrc20 for both Tableau and SSMS.